# Как используется таблица разделов MBR?

Tags: mbr, загрузчик

Зачем необходима таблица разделов? Если для возможности загружать несколько систем, то можно же написать такой загрузчик, который будет их загружать и без таблицы разделов. Получается, таблица разделов MBR - всего лишь стандарт их перечисления?

Answer (score 0):

Таблица разделов нужна, чтобы разделить один жесткий диск на несколько разделов. Это может потребоваться по разным причинам, от разграничения прав, до ограничения на размер файловой системы.

Стандартизация была нужна для того, чтобы зашить код работы с ФС и разделами в ПЗУ BIOS (basic input/output system - базовая система ввода/вывода), и таким образом избавить древние ОС от этого кода.

Так как в те времена экономили каждый байт, то в MBR поместили сразу две вещи.
Собственно загрузчик 446 байта и таблицу разделов - 64 байта.